# Analyzer to autocomplete names

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I want to be able autocomplete names.

For example, if we have the name `John Smith`, I want to be able to search for `Jo` and `Sm` and `John Sm` to get the document back.

In addition, I do not want `jo sm` matching the document.

I currently have this analyzer:

```
return array(
    'settings' => array(
        'index' => array(
            'analysis' => array(
                'analyzer' => array(
                    'autocomplete' => array(
                        'tokenizer' => 'autocompleteEngram',
                        'filter' => array('lowercase', 'whitespace')
                    )
                ),

                'tokenizer' => array(
                    'autocompleteEngram' => array(
                        'type' => 'edgeNGram',
                        'min_gram' => 1,
                        'max_gram' => 50
                    )
                )
            )   
        )
    )
);
```

The problem with this is that first we split the text up and then tokenize using edgengrams.

This results in this:
`j` `jo` `joh` `john` `s` `sm` `smi` `smit` `smith`

This means, if I search for `john smith` or `john sm`, nothing would be returned.

So, I need to be generate tokens that look like this:
`j` `jo` `joh` `john` `s` `sm` `smi` `smit` `smith` `john s` `john sm` `john smi` `john smit` `john smith`.

How can I set up my analyzer so that I generates those extra tokens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up not using edgengrams.

I created an analyzer with the `standard` tokenizer, and `standard` and `lowercase` filters. This is virtually identical to the `standard` analyser, but does not have any stopwords filter (we are searching for names after all, and there might be someone called `The` or `An` etc).

I then set the above analyzer as the `index_analyzer` and `simple` as the `search_analyzer`. Using this setup with a `match_phrase_prefix` query worked really well.

This is the custom analyser I used (called autocomplete and expressed in PHP):

```
'autocomplete' => array(
                        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                        'filter' => array('standard', 'lowercase')
                ),
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Could you please share the json settings?